# Handling simplexml to array elegantly

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an xml structure:

```
<node1><node2><child_1/><child_2/><child_3/></node2></node1>
```

And i would want to get an array like this:

```
['child_1', 'child_2', 'child_3']
```

But to make my method for creating this handle errors elegantly and return an empty array when nothing found i am having to do this:

```
public function testXmlParse()
{
    $config = new SimpleXMLElement("<node1><node2><child_1/><child_2/><child_3/></node2></node1>");
    $result = $config->xpath('/node1/node2');

    if (! count($result)) {
        return [];
    }

    $result = $result[0]->children();
}
```

But i have even more code to write to check for arrays and valid etc.

Is there an elegantly way to get the correct result and return 0 on nothing finding?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written won't return an array anyway - the result of `->children()` is an iterable `SimpleXMLElement` object. However, you can take advantage of the fact that a zero-element object is still iterable with `foreach`, and will simply go round zero times.

Since you are always looking for the first match, your example can also use SimpleXML access instead of XPath, to avoid the extra logic there.

```
$config = new SimpleXMLElement("<node1><node2><child_1/><child_2/><child_3/></node2></node1>");
// Start with an empty array; if no children are found, it will stay empty
$results = [];
// Note: $config represents the <node1> element, not the document
foreach ( $config->node2->children() as $name => $element ) {
    $results[] = $name;
}
```

If `<node2>` is not always present, you may need to add an extra `if ( isset($config->node2) )` around the loop, to avoid PHP throwing you warnings.